# Exceute SP with out parameter using Dapper always get null value (Dapper+ODBC+Sybase)

Tags: odbc, sybase, dapper

I have problem executing SP with Dapper using ODBC Sybase, for input parameter I do not have any problems, when I tried out parameter is not working as expected.

Original SP have insert statement so I put TRANSACTION statement in the code.

Here my modified SP:

```
create proc dbo.SP_TEST_DAPPER(@FIRST_PARM VARCHAR(10),  @ErrorMessages VARCHAR(1000 ) Out  )
AS 

BEGIN 

  declare @Rtn Int  
  declare @TranName  varchar(50)

  SELECT @TranName = 'SP_TEST' 

  BEGIN TRANSACTION @TranName 
  IF @FIRST_PARM = '1'
  BEGIN 
      SELECT @ErrorMessages   = 'OK'  
  END 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT @ErrorMessages   = 'Error'  
      GOTO ERROR_TRAP  
  END 

  COMMIT TRANSACTION @TranName   
  SELECT @ErrorMessages
    ERROR_TRAP:  
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @TranName   
  SELECT @ErrorMessages      
END
```

My result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation for ODBC named parameters is incorrect.  You encase the named parameter with question marks in your statement and create the named parameter without the question marks.  The question marks are used by Dapper to parse the statement to find the names.

```
storedProcedureName = "dbo.SP_TEST_DAPPER ?FIRST_PARM?, ?ErrorMessages?";

pX.Add("FIRST_PARM",firstparm);
pX.Add("ErrorMessages", dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 1000);
```

See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26484944/6490042